# How can I suspend a project in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I suspend a project in GAS?

I have two projects on GAS, one is an outdated project so I want to stop it from working. But I don't know how to.

Some webpage says to delete the project, but I want to keep it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I solved it by myself.

[Deployment] on the top, [Manage Deployment] and then archive all the deployment. Then it is suspended and I can resume it afterward.

Have a nice afternoon everyone.

Comment: You can delete the project and save the code using Apps Script API